Why am I seeing SET NAMES UTF8 collation repeatedly in the MySQL (MariaDB) general log and slow query log
I'm attempting to troubleshoot why a PHP script is running slower on MariaDB 10.5.22 (~10 mins) than on MySQL 5.6 (~1 min). It's a simple script that takes data from a CSV file and uploads to a table. For some reason, I'm seeing the following repeatedly in the MySQL general log:
4332471 Connect myuser@10.20.30.40 on mydatabase using TCP/IP
4332471 Query   SET NAMES UTF8
4332471 Quit    
4332472 Connect myuser@10.20.30.40 on mydatabase using TCP/IP
4332472 Query   SET NAMES UTF8
4332472 Quit    
4332473 Connect myuser@10.20.30.40 on mydatabase using TCP/IP
4332473 Query   SET NAMES UTF8
4332473 Quit

In the slow query log, I see:
SET timestamp=1720100123;
# administrator command: Quit;
# Time: 240704 14:35:24
# User@Host: myuser[myuser] @  [10.20.30.40]
# Thread_id: 1801710  Schema: mydatabase  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 0.000044  Lock_time: 0.000000  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 11
use mydatabase;
SET timestamp=1720100124;
SET NAMES UTF8;
# User@Host: myuser[myuser] @  [10.20.30.40]
# Thread_id: 1801710  Schema: mydatabase  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 0.000001  Lock_time: 0.000000  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 0
SET timestamp=1720100124;
# administrator command: Quit;
# User@Host: myuser[myuser] @  [10.20.30.40]
# Thread_id: 1801711  Schema: mydatabase  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 0.000021  Lock_time: 0.000000  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 11
SET timestamp=1720100124;
SET NAMES UTF8;

The database collation is:
+----------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value             |
+----------------------+-------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci   |
| collation_database   | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_server     | latin1_swedish_ci |
+----------------------+-------------------+

+--------------------------+----------------------+
| @@character_set_database | @@collation_database |
+--------------------------+----------------------+
| utf8                     | utf8_bin             |
+--------------------------+----------------------+

Any ideas why SET NAMES UTF8  is appearing repeatedly?

I would guess your client is doing that each time it connects; is there a reason it would be connecting more than once?  if it is reconnecting for each separate insert or something, that will definitely make it much slower

It doesn't appear to be the PHP script making these individual connections. I'm attempting to work out which other client is generating these.

what slow query log settings do you have? Note especially long_query_time

The question is tagged as mariadb, but the slow query log looks like a MySQL slow query log.

@danblack I set the long_query_time = 0 to capture everything, ran my script but reset it to 10 secs again.

@GeorgRichter select @@version returns  10.5.22-MariaDB-log.

What framework are you using?

@RickJames Using PHP Symfony v6.

Sounds like Symphony is being overly cautious.

In the MariaDB client server protocol, the sever sends in his initial handshake packet information about the default collation.
Theoretically, this information could be checked by a client connector: If the
value is e.g. 33, the client knows that the collation is utf8mb3_general_ci.
However the client connector can't rely on this information anymore:

The protocol only supports 1 byte for collation information, over the last years more and more collations were added, so the total amount of available collations excceds 255 (1 byte)
The information was sent before TLS handshake, so in case of a MitM-Attack this information is not trustable
Wnen connecting to a proxy (e.g. MaxScale, MySQL Proxy) the collation of the proxy will be sent, which might be different from the endpoint.

The client of course could retrieve the character sets and check if he needs to change the character set, but this would be much more expensive then sending a simple SET NAMES utf8.
Therefore most "modern" connectors send this information explicitly. Speaking of PHP (mysqlnd) it is utf8mb3 for MySQL version < 5.6, otherwise utf8mb4.
